# Use calender_date_select with rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, calendar

I successfully installed calender_date_select of 1.16.3 version

I included `<%= calendar_date_select_includes %>` tag in my layouts  after
`<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` Tag ...

And in my view i'm using

```
<%= f.calendar_date_select :whatever %>
```

But when i run the application it was showing the error like ..

```
undefined local variable or method `calendar_date_select_includes' for #<#<Class:0x2949588>:0x2947ed8>
```

Can anybody please help me to resolve this problem .....

Answer (score 1):

you should install prototype, in rails 3.1 jquery is used by default.
but calendar date select use prototype